# What does mean CD, FD and MD on the Jeppesen LTBR VORB chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, jeppesen

[image]

Hello all,

I just wanted to ask the meaning of CD068, FD068 and MD068. 068 is the course but i cannot find any info about CD,FD and MD.

Also, at the VOR A 25R chart, I saw FS250. Can you share their meaning? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

They are database identifiers for waypoints that aren't named.

- MX### and MD### waypoints are missed approach waypoints
- FD### waypoints are final approach fixes
- CD### waypoints occur further out on the approach; I believe that the "C" stands for "course", as in a waypoint that defines part of the approach course.
- FS### waypoint seems to be an FAF for, specifically, a VOR approach, and is designated when there are multiple approaches that would otherwise use duplicate identifiers.

More info on pages 8 & 9 at the [link](http://www.jeppesen.com/download/navdata/navdata_info1.pdf) that DeepSpace posted.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Jeppesen's "NAME CONVENTIONS WAYPOINT IDENTIFIERS"](http://www.jeppesen.com/download/navdata/navdata_info1.pdf), in a VOR approach the CD, FD and MD points are FACF (Final Approach Course Fix), FAF (Final Approach Fix) and MAP (missed approach fix) respectively.